# Gamma Distribution Engineering system fails

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let $Y$ denote the time until an engineering system fails. An engineer models Y as a gamma random variable with $α= 2$ and $β= 2.$ Find $P(Y > 2).$

Using this definition gamma distribution

$$ g(x;α,β) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{1}{β^{α}\Gamma(α) 
} \cdot x^{α-1}e^{-x/β} & \text{for x > 0}\\ 
0 &\text{ elsewhere} \\ 
\end{array} \
\right.  $$

Where $α>0$ and $β>0$

---

My attempt Density Function

$$ g(x;2,2) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{1}{{8\Gamma 
}} \cdot xe^{-x/2} & \text{for y > 0}\\ 
0 &\text{ elsewhere} \\ 
\end{array} \
\right.  $$

$P(Y>2) =\int^{2}_{0} \frac{1}{8}xe^{-x/2}dy$

Would this be the correct way of setting the problem up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors: You left a mysterious $\Gamma$ in the denominator of your distribution; that factor should be
$$ \frac{1}{2^{2\Gamma(2)}} = \frac{1}{4} $$
(you did notice that $\Gamma(2) = 1! - 1$, not $2$, right?)

And your integral for $P(Y>2)$ should go from $2$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Never mind I see what you mean about $\Gamma$

Comment: What is then $5\Gamma$ then by the by?